# See POST parameters

Tags: ios, xcode

Im sending (with ASIFormDataRequest) a POST request, with 4 parameters. The server launches a NullPointerException when this request arrives. When I debug the app, I don't know how to actually see what's inside the parameters in the request done by the phone. Is there any way to achieve this? Maybe I am missing some option in XCode?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the post parameters, you will need to look inside `yourFormRequest.postBody`, but please note the data is `NSMutableData` so you will have to convert it to `NSString` or `NSDictionary`

Like following

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[yourFormRequest.postBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: It says "Expected identifiers". Im digging on it... Thank you!